# Independent azure Web job is not able to connect to SQL Server hosted in an Azure VM

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-sql-server

Independent Azure Web job is not able to connect to SQL Server hosted in an Azure VM.

But we are able to connect to the same SQL SERVER from our local computers.

Error details :

> The underlying provider failed on Open.
>
> The job failed with exception :
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is known.)

Comment: 1.Use the full name of the server you are connecting to (myserver.database.windows.net) not something else.2.Configure the firewall in Azure Sql Database.3. You could  configure SQL to listen a specific port (1433 and 1434) and open that port on the firewall. Check the link.http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823938 4.The connection string should be connectionString="Server=...." .

Answer (score 0):

Is the webjob able to connect to the SQL DB hosted in Azure VM now? Also, is the Azure VM hosted in west Europe? If yes, you might have received a message on the Azure portal and Service Health Dashboard (banner).

Comment: No .. still we are not able to connect. SQL SERVER IN AZURE VM is up and running

Comment: Have we white listed the outbound IP addresses mentioned in the properties blade of the webapp in Azure portal?